# Read frame types from compressed video

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to do an analysis on compressed videos, in order to save the calculations of the decoding part.

So I want to read a compressed video, and check each frame if it's an I/B/P frame, and do a certain action (process), depending on the type of  frame.

How can I do this using `ffmpeg`? I haven't seen in the documentation how to read a compressed video.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you do *not* actually want to process the frame, only its type, correct? That requires low-level bitstream access, ffmpeg doesn’t deal with that.

Comment: I want to process the frames! @bertieb, editted my question and changed the meaning of the question.
I want to process each frame , given the type of the frame, I,B,P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Determining frame type using `ffmpeg` or `ffprobe`

You want to work through a video file, checking frame types as you go. I have had reason to do this in the past. [Gyan Doshi's answer over on SO covers this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37560890):

> ```
> ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf select='eq(n,334)',showinfo -f null -
> ```
>
> The above will produce an output for the 335th frame of the video
>
> ```
> n: 0 pts: 171008 pts_time:11.1333 pos:  1090471 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:1280x720 
> i:P iskey:0 type:B checksum:A72D197D plane_checksum:[9008E835 680AC49A 6CD66C90] 
> mean:[136 122 134] stdev:[65.4 7.0 9.5]
> ```
>
> You can skip the select filter and get output for all frames and then grep like [incBrain does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37556523). Note that you want the display picture number, not coded.

*(additional link not present in answer added by me)*

Depending on how you want to go about it, you have the option of using a `select` filter as above, or grabbing the info for all frames (using `ffprobe video.mp4 -show_frames`) and processing the output from that.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer but not pasted here, use display_picture_number, not coded, if going the grep route. The latter tracks the encoding order and does not represent the order in which the frames are displayed.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks for the heads up, the last line probably got truncated when I added the link

Comment: Thanks! you helped me so much .
I have a few more questions (small ones) :


1.if I want to pass on all the frames in the video, I can just do a simple for loop on : select='eq(n,i) , right?  2. There is a way to plot the frame in a "meaningful" way? I saw in an article they ploted the I frames using HSV, have an Idea for that?

3. There is no need for :"display_picture_number" if I'll loop on the select operator? because I remember there is an order issue in h264/mp4.

Comment: One more thing I want also to read the frame, means to store his matrix and do calculations on her, possible?

Comment: @albert1905 If you have follow up questions those are best addressed in new questions; some of the things you are asking may be too broad for SU though- it will depend what you want to achieve

Comment: I am quite rusty- I just dug out a script for unrelated reasons which happens to  deal with different frame types -- quite a coincidence! -- last time I touched it was July 2015 (it seems that I used incBrain's approach, rather than @Gyan 's, though the script predates both answers so I may have gotten the usage advice from the ffmpeg-user mailing list...)